# Inverse of SPD matrix + identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I didn't know exactly where to post this question. I feel like it falls between Computer Science and Mathematics, so I'm sorry if it doesn't fit here.

I need to calculate $(A+\alpha I)^{-1}$, given $\alpha>0$ and $A^{-1}$ which is SPD, and with a known sparsity pattern. (If it helps in any way, I need it for calculating Mahalanobis distance)

I'm dealing with an high dimension and sparse $A^{-1}$ so I would also like to avoid calculating $A$ (or any other inverse) using the inverse operation.

I tried looking into Woodbury Matrix Identity, but I can't find a way to use it in my case.
Is there any closed form solution or iterative method that I can use?
Is the fact that I need only to calculate $x^T(A+\alpha I)^{-1}x$ can help in any way?

**update:**
I found an interesting way to avoid calculating $A$ out of $A^{-1}$ for this:

$(A+\alpha I)^{-1} = (A+\alpha AA^{-1})^{-1} = (A(I+\alpha A^{-1}))^{-1} = (I+\alpha A^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}$

So now when calculating the Mahalanobis distance I need:
$x^T(I+\alpha A^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}x$

Now I only need to do one inverse operation.
$A^{-1}$ is somewhat of a k-diagonal matrix.
So maybe now I'll find a way to calculate what i need more efficiently.

Comment: Look up krylov methods

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, the Woodbury Matrix Identity is of no use since the perturbation of $\alpha I$ is not low rank. In addition, in general, computing a full eigendecomposition $A=QDQ^T$ will be much slower than just using sparse Gaussian elimination on $A+\alpha I$, so this won't be helpful either in practice.

As a commenter suggested, this may be a good time for preconditioned conjugate gradient, a Krylov subspace method. For $\alpha$ small, we have $A + \alpha I \approx A$ so $A^{-1}(A+\alpha I) \approx I$. Thus, $A^{-1}$, which you already know, should provide a good preconditioner. If a better preconditioner is needed and $\alpha \|A^{-1}\| < 1$ for an appropriate matrix norm, then we have the Neumann series

$$
(A+\alpha I)^{-1} = A^{-1}(I+\alpha A^{-1})^{-1} = A^{-1} - \alpha A^{-2} + \alpha^2 A^{-3}-\cdots.
$$

You can truncate this infinite series up to the $A^{-k}$ power and evaluate the preconditioner $(A^{-1} - \alpha A^{-2} + \alpha^2 A^{-3} -\cdots + (-1)^{k+1}A^{-k})x$ using $k$ matrix-vector products with $A^{-1}$ using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

If instead $\alpha$ is very large, specifically $\|A\|/\alpha < 1$, then we can instead use the Neuman series

$$
(A+\alpha I)^{-1} = \alpha^{-1}(I+\alpha^{-1}A)^{-1} = \alpha^{-1}I - \alpha^{-2}A + \alpha^{-3}A - \cdots
$$

as a preconditioner. If $\alpha$ is somewhere in between, then neither of these Neumann series ideas will work, and you might want to investigate another preconditioner if you intend to use Conjugate Gradient. ([Algebraic multigrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrid_method#Algebraic_MultiGrid_(AMG)) may work well, for instance.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All my $A^{-1}$ come from a special case GMM, so I don't know if I can bound $||A||/\alpha$. But I'll check it!

Comment: What do you mean by GMM?

Comment: The matrices are cov/precision matrices from a gaussian mixture model

Answer (score 1):

[For every symmetric real matrix $A$ there exists a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ$ is a diagonal matrix. Every symmetric matrix is thus, up to choice of an orthonormal basis, a diagonal matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) If you can find it, then $A=QDQ^T$ and your expression becomes $Q(D+\alpha I)^{-1}Q^T.$ Since $A$ is positive semidefinite, $(D+\alpha I)^{-1}$ with $\alpha>0$, exists even when $A^{-1}$ does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, A is positive definite, so $A^{-1}$ exists (and in fact it's whats given). The complexity of eigendecomposition is also $O(n^3)$ which is like inverting (if I remember correctly). I'll update the post with something I found to somewhat reduce the calculation of $A$ out of $A^{-1}$.